# sqlite query duplicating data in results

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite DB with multiple tables representing employees of a hospital. Each one has in common a firstname, lastname, and category column.  I want to simply list the first name, last name and category of all the workers of the hospital.

My query is:

```
Select Volunteer.*, Nurse.*, Administrator.*, doctor.firstname, doctor.lastname, doctor.category
FROM Volunteer, Nurse, Administrator, doctor
WHERE Volunteer.category = 'Volunteer'
OR Nurse.category = 'Nurse'
OR Administrator.category = 'Administrator'
OR doctor.category = 'doctor'
```

Each table has 8-10 entries, so I would expect the query to return about 40 rows.  It returns about 1000 instead.

I am new to SQL, and understand why the number of rows being returned is happening.  I believe I need to use a LEFT JOIN statement, but I dont understand the structure very well.  Could someone help correct my query and I will work backwards to figure out the rest?  Thanks.

Comment: Please include table structure for all 4 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing a join where all you want to do is to union the tables:

```
(Select firstname, lastname, category
FROM Volunteer
UNION
Select firstname, lastname, category
FROM Nurse)
UNION
(Select firstname, lastname, category
FROM Administrator
UNION
Select firstname, lastname, category
FROM doctor)
```

The form of the above is correct. I am not sure if needs more parentheses.